# expected value of random variable times sample mean

Tags: probability, expectation, statistical-inference

> Assume a population of $M$ numbers, where $M_i$ have values $y_i$, $i = 1,2,...,k$; thus $\sum_{i=1}^k{M_i} = M$. Thus the population mean is 
>   $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^k{\frac{M_iy_i}{M}}$ 
>   and the population variance is: 
>   $\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k{\frac{M_i(y_i-\mu)^2}{M}}$
>   Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$, $n\le M$ be $n$ values selected at random, without replacement, from the population

Given an $X_i$, how would you evaluate:
 
$E[X_i\bar{X}] = E[X_i\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{n}{X_i}}]$

This is part of a larger problem I'm working on, where I'm trying to evaluate $E[S^2]$, where $S^2$ is:
$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$

unfortunately when working out the expression for $E[S^2]$, I got to a step where I needed to evaluate $E{\left[X_i\bar{X}\right]}$ and I got stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you evaluate $E[X_i\bar{X}]$?

The simple answer is: you don't.

At some point in the derivation of the expected value of the 
sample variance $S^2$,
one usually has written something equivalent to
$$
\mathbb E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\bar X
                  + \sum_{i=1}^n \bar X^2 \right].
$$

You may be tempted to apply the sum-of-expectations formula to
the middle term,
$$
\mathbb E \left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\bar X\right]
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E \left[X_i\bar X\right]
$$
and then look at each term in the summation on the right individually,
but a better way is to remember that
$$
\bar X = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n \bar X.
$$
Recognizing that $\bar X$ has the same value in each of the terms
$X_i \bar X$, we can take it out of the sum as a constant factor:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \bar X = \bar X \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.
$$

So now we can write
$$
\mathbb E \left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\bar X\right]
= \mathbb E \left[\bar X\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]
= \mathbb E \left[\bar X\left(n \bar X\right)\right]
= \mathbb E \left[n \bar X^2\right]
= n \mathbb E \left[\bar X^2\right],
$$
and we no longer see the individual $X_i \bar X$ terms.

Comment: Thanks David. I was thinking that you could treat $\bar{X}$ as a constant, but convinced myself that was inappropriate in this context. Maybe just a little too late at night to be doing this problem...

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\bar X$ is not a constant in the sense that $2$ or (in this case) $\sigma^2$ are--but it is "constant across all the terms", that is, you can use the distributive law of multiplication over addition. It's basically a case of $ab + ac = a(b+c)$.